# How can I compute injective hulls of geometric quotients of noetherian rings by prime ideals?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, injective-module

If $R$ is a noetherian ring, there is a theorem stating that all of the simple injective modules are the injective hulls $E(R/\mathfrak{p})$ for $\mathfrak{p}$ prime. How can I compute the injective hull of for some geometric modules? For example
$$
\begin{align*}
R = \mathbb{C}[x,y] && \mathfrak{p} = (x^2 + y) \\
R = \frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]}{(x^4 + y^4 + z^4)} && \mathfrak{p} = (x^2 - yz)
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Let $R$ be a dvr with maximal ideal $\pi R$ and $k=R/\pi R$. Do you know how to calculate the injective hull of $k$ over $R$? If you know this, the first question should be easy.

Comment: I don't. How can I do this, and where can I find this?

Comment: Consider the inclusion $R/\pi^n R\to R/\pi^{n+1}R$ given by multiplication by $\pi$. Take the direct limit and that is the injective hull of $k$. Or in other words, take the natural inclusion $R\to R_{\pi}$ and the quotient is the injective hull.